# Where can I find a list of Tags for the Lyx Document processor?

Tags: lyx

Is there a list of tags that lyx uses somewhere defined?  And is there a comment tag?

Not like a comment box, but simply a no-op sequence (% doesn't seem to work) so I can delineate blocks of code.

I can insert blocks of code using vim safer and faster than with the gui, but I want to use lyx for display (instead of power-point).  But once I've inserted them, it's easy to lose where one is.  If I could delineate these blocks of code with lines like:

```
  %%%%%% begin inset %%%%%%%%
...

  %%%%%%%% end inset %%%%%%%%
```

Answer (score 0):

The best source for Lyx Tags is the Lyx Frequently asked questions (FAQs) on their Wiki site.

[You can access it here](http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/)